# In what Security Zone should SharePoint Online (Office 365) be added?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, security

I was wondering in what [Security Zone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/174360) SharePoint Online (Office 365) should be added?

I'm not sure if the Office 365 site(s) belong in the security zone Trusted Sites Zone or in Local Intranet Zone.

What are the URL's I should add?

Is there any official documentation from Microsoft regarding the Security Zone to be used?

Comment: Add in Trusted Sites Zone, my sites url and sharepoint portal url. It hsould be enoth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft suggests [using the default security settings of Internet Explorer for Office 365](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/197700). 
But if problems comes with singing in/out, editing documents, etc, then you need to add URLs to both Trusted Sites zone and Local Intranet zone:

*Add to IE’s Trusted sites zone:*

```
https://*.outlook.com/ 

https://*.sharepoint.com/ 

https://*.microsoftonline.com/ 

https://*.lync.com/
```

*Add to Local intranet zone:*

```
*.microsoftonline.com

*.sharepoint.com

*.outlook.com

*.lync.com
```

More info from Microsoft [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2507767)

Comment: From my experience, usually it is enough to add only to Trusted sites.