# SharePoint Online using ActiveX object

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to run a exe file in my local machine through javascript. I use

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">  
     MyObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" )  
     function RunExe()   
     {  
        MyObject.Run('"file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/app.exe" "hello" "hi"') ;  
    }  

</script>
```

This script runs fine when I create a `aspx` page and run from it. But it doesn't work if this is added to the script editor webpart. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's your browser? Do you see any entries in browser console (F12)?

Comment: Start with inspecting what SharePoint makes of this in the HTML delivered to the browser (not the source you paste into the WebPart)

Comment: @AzizKabyshev  browser IE11  the error I get is 'unable to get property Run of undefined or null reference'. Once I put the initialization inside the function, I get 'automation server cant create object'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have wrapped your code inside script tag even in script editor web part.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">//code</script>
```

source: [This reference](http://paulryan.com.au/2014/script-editor-runs-javascript-edit-mode/)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it works fine in **Content Editor Web Part**. Just tried this code:

```
<script>
    MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    function RunNotepad()
    {
        MyObject.Run("C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");
        return true;
    }
</script>
<input onclick="return RunNotepad()" type="button" value="Run Notepad"/>
```

As long as we are discussing SharePoint Online, your SP addresses should already be included in one of IE's **security zones**. I've got 4 `https://{site}.sharepoint.com` entries in `Trusted` zone, but you may want to take a look at [In what Security Zone should SharePoint Online (Office 365) be added?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159127/in-what-security-zone-should-sharepoint-online-office-365-be-added) or search for official recommendations from Microsoft.

Then I've opened `IE` -> `Tools` -> `Internet Options` -> `Security` tab, selected `Trusted` zone, pressed `Custom level...` and set ActiveX-related options to `Prompt`. Now at the page load I see this:

[image]

`notepad` is launched fine from that button now.

---

So you see there is nothing SP-related here - it's IE security restrictions in action. Adjust your security zone settings, and script will work 100%. But stay informed that it lowers overall security.