# Internet Explorer restricting webpage

Tags: sharepoint-online, internet-explorer

When opening intra, I am getting this message:

> Internet explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or
>   activex controls.

This is affecting approximately for 100 persons. What is wrong with SharePoint and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Following thing you can do in order to fix this issue

Add the website to the trusted site and Disable ActiveX Filtering for the Trusted Sites zone

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the intra site to a trusted site in Internet Explorer. See for example this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-do-i-add-a-site-to-my-trusted-sites-list/98cc77c8-b364-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5).

Also see this related question: [In what Security Zone should SharePoint Online (Office 365) be added?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159127/in-what-security-zone-should-sharepoint-online-office-365-be-added/159133#159133)